# Searching multiple strings in excel to include a full word match while ignoring semi-colons

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, string-matching

I have an excel table with a field called "key words" containing several words that vary for each record. I have another field called "pharmacology category" which has a formula that will output "yes" if any of a custom, predefined list of terms appear in a "key words" field record and "no" if not.

The issue I'm having is that fragments of words turn up as "yes" in this formula, e.g. if the word "agonist" appears in the "key words" field and my "pharmacology category" list has "antagonist" defined as a word, this will result in a "yes" because it's contained within the word.

To overcome this I can use spaces either side of the word when creating the word list - " agonist ". This would solve the problem, however because sometimes these words are separated by a semi-colon, the word " agonist;" would not return a "yes" in this instance.

I need a way to run this search to treat these semi-colons as spaces. The closest solution I've found is using the substitute command [discussed here](https://superuser.com/questions/479161/find-match-whole-word-only-workaround) but I'm struggling to integrate it into my existing formula without errors.

The working formula I am using so far is below:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" Drug effects "," Drug therapy "," antagonist " },C2)))>0,"YES","NO")
```

This assumes cell C2 contains the "key words" record which may look something like "antagonist; agonist; DNA;" etc.

I just need this tweaked to ignore semi-colons so that "antagonist;" will appear as "yes" when "  antagonist " is included in the predefined word list.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" Drug effects "," Drug therapy "," antagonist " },   SUBSTITUTE(C2, ";", " ")   )))>0,"YES","NO")`

Comment: =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" Drug effects "," Drug therapy "," antagonist "}," "&SUBSTITUTE(C2,";"," ")))),"YES","NO")

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Both these solutions work well.